# Sitecore advanced upload option is missing from admin panel

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I was trying to upload an image using Sitecore [Version 6.5] media library to my existing sitecore website. I see the **Advance Upload Files** option is completly missing. Later, I tried to install a default sitecore instance and I see the Advanced Upload option is there. But it is completely missing to the existing sitecore website.

Here, is the snapshot of my site where the Advanced upload option is completely missing:

[image: Here, is the snapshot of my site where the Advanced upload option is completely missing:]

And here is the snapshot of my default sitecore site where the Advanced upload option is there:

[image]

To fix this, I tried to change couple of configuration files. But still the same issue. The Advanced upload files option is completely missing. Did you face the same type of issue or if you know how to fix this issue, can you please share your thoughts. Or if I need to change any of the configuration files, then can you share your thoughts  about that change of any of the configuration file?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Upload files (Advanced)` button is hidden in 2 cases:

1. Folder does not use `Media Folder` template. Just check your folders - maybe they use standard `Folder` template instead of `Media Folder`.
2. `Upload.Classic` setting is set to false. Open `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and look for `Upload.Classic` value. When it's set to true, Sitecore uses flash upload instead.

If none of above is the case, maybe you have some custom code which hides `Upload files (Advanced)` button from you editors.

Comment: I see, there is only one line of code into showconfig.aspx file:   "<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ShowConfig.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sitecore.sitecore.admin.ShowConfig" %>"

Comment: Do not open the showconfig file in editor. Open it in your browser using `http://.../sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`. I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: plz, ignore the 2nd comment. already deleted.  Also opened it using the browser but i see the same line

Comment: @blueMoon open the showconfig as follows: http://[domain]/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx